# requestFileSystem() in cordova not work on android app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, intellij-idea

I just add plugin file,file-transfer, device in cordova 3.3.0 and try to make own file explorer but when I type `requestFileSystem()` in intelliJ idea 13.0.1 ultimate edition tool tip appeared

> Unresolved function or method requestFileSystem

and I know this function will not work in my app. How to use this function?? what should I add to make this function work? Thanks for your help.